# ¿Cómo llamar a una función IIFE en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iife

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
(function resize(){
    console.log("Ayuda!!")
})();

window.onresize = function(){ resize() }
```

El mensaje que se muestra en el console.log es solo de ejemlo, evidentemente tengo algo más complejo que eso, el caso es que cuando intento llamar a esa función cuando se redimensione la pantalla me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: resize is not defined

he intentado también esto:

```
window.onresize = resize()
```

Pero tampoco funciona, agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el *scope*, pues la función `resize()` está dentro de los paréntesis y añadir `()` al final, lo que haces es invocarla

```js
(function resize(){
    console.log("Ayuda!!")
})();
```

Si le quitas `()` e intentas acceder a la función fuera de los paréntesis, aún así no funcionará

```js
(function resize(){
    console.log("Ayuda!!")
});

resize();
```

Pues el *scope* de la función es únicamente dentro de los paréntesis, normalmente se usan funciones como la que has estructurado para definir funciones anónimas

```js
(() => {
  console.log("función anónima");
})();
```

---

Lo que puedes hacer es algo así

```js
var resize = (() => {
    console.log("Ayuda!!")
});

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Las `IIFE` tienen la característica de ejecutarse en el mismo momento de ser declaradas y no se guardan en ningún `scope` que las contenga (crean su propio scope). En este caso estás declarando la función, ejecutándola al momento y al llamar a la función `onresize` se consulta el `scope` de `window` pero ahí no se ha hecho ninguna asignación de la función `resize` por lo que te da ese error de que no se ha definido.

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) tienes más información sobra las IIFE

```
(function () {
    statements
})();
```

> The first is the anonymous function with lexical scope enclosed within
> the Grouping Operator (). This prevents accessing variables within the
> IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope
>
> La primera primera parte de la IIFE (la que está entre paréntesis)
> tiene su propio lexical scope. Esto previene el acceso a variables
> internas de la IIFE además de evitar contaminar el global scope

Si no la conocer, te recomiendo la genial serie de libros "You don't know Js yet" de Kyle Simpson ([enlace](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)) en la que explica con muchísima profundidad el funcionamiento de los scopes, las closures y demás conceptos relacionados.

Comment: ¿Podrías traducir la cita en español?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede registrar una función anónima en el evento `onresize` del global scope `window`, dentro del scope de la función `IIFE`:

```
//IIFE
( window.onresize = function(){ console.log("Ayuda!!") })()
```

De esta forma, cada que suceda el evento se tendrá esa función anónima en la lista de tareas, lista para ser ejecutada.

Aquí un demo, aplíca un resize a tu explorador para ver la `consola`:

```js
( window.onresize = function(){ console.log("Ayuda!!") })()
```